# このコードの for (i=1, len=arguments.length; i<len; ++i) はどういう意味？

Tags: javascript

**リンク先の「クラスの継承」に、下記記述があるのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？**

・extend関数へ渡されたoオブジェクト引数の数だけループを回した上に、oオブジェクト引数の各内容毎に(？)ループを回して、生成したインスタンスのプロパティとして設定する？

```
/**
 * Object.createの拡張関数
 */
function extend(o) {
  var f = extend.f, i, len, n, prop;
```

//中略

```
  for (i=1, len=arguments.length; i<len; ++i) {
    for (prop in arguments[i]) {
      n[prop] = arguments[i][prop];
    }
  }
```

http://qiita.com/Hiraku/items/16e88b999bd82d86aa66

Comment: 原題には「クラス継承する際」と書かれていましたが、これがJavascriptで一般的なクラス継承のパターンというわけでもなく、その記事オリジナルの実装のようなのでタイトルを変更しました。加えて、ここで訊くよりQiitaのコメント欄で尋ねたほうが著者から的確な回答が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 言葉足らずだったので少し修正致しました。

**arguments**と言うのは**function**に渡された引数が格納される
ローカルの配列のようなもの(※似ているけど配列と同じではない)です。
functionを呼び出す時にextend(o,p,q,…)と引数が入力された場合にo以外は
変数の割当が記述されていないけどp,q,…に該当する引数も取り出す事が出来ます。

質問文のjavascriptは**extend**に与えられた引数を全て取り出しています。

> 第1引数 = function extend(**o**) で記述された **o** (arguments[0]と同等)
>   第2引数 = **arguments[1]** 
>   第3引数 = **arguments[2]**
>   第n引数 = **arguments[n-1]**

外側のfor句の開始が**i=1**なのでfor文で第2引数(**arguments[1]**)以降の引数を順番に処理しています。

```
for (i=1, len=arguments.length; i<len; ++i) {
```

内側の**for～in**は対象の引数の列挙可能プロパティ(**prop**)を取得して
順番に**n**に格納していくというものです。

```
for (prop in arguments[i]) {
  n[prop] = arguments[i][prop];
}
```

**n**はループの外で宣言されたオブジェクトなので
 n[prop] = ～とすると後から来た引数の中に
同じプロパティ名があった場合は上書きされます。

尚、質問文に抜粋された部分では**o**は使用していません。
**o**には第1引数が入っており、arguments[0]と同等ですが、
ループ部分は第2引数(arguments[1])以降を処理しています。

Comment: 「oは使用していません。oには1つ目の引数だけが入っています」。どういう意味でしょうか？　「extendに与えられた引数」はoではない？

Comment: iの初期値が1なので、第一引数oは除外されるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `arguments[0] === o`です。`extend`には引数が`o`しか定義されていませんが、2つ以上の引数が与えられていても、`arguments[i]`で取り出せます。

Comment: 言葉足らずだったので解答を詳しく修正致しました。